# Python writing polynomial one line code

Tags: python, printing, equation

I have a list of polynomial equation constants and I want to write this equation with for loop inside print() function. What is the shortest way (if one-line code exist would be more appropriate)?

EDIT: (reason: adding a sample)
The code is below:

```
cnst=list()
degree=int(input("Enter degree of your polynomial: "))
#degree=int(input("Enter degree of your polynomial: "))
# must use degree+1 to include constant term
for i in range(degree+1):
    print(i)
    print("Enter constant for x^" + str(degree-i) + ": ", end='')
    cnst.append(float(input()))
print (cnst)
print("\nFunction created: ")
#print equation code here <<--
```

Comment: What is the equation? Can you give us a sample of expected output?

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34843707/4737952

Comment: Serious? "Polynomial equation" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) our Pythonic mathematical lord and savior.

You can add, subtract, calculate derivatives, etc. The [`np.polynomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.polynomials.html) module has a **lot** of functions. `numpy.polynomial` is now the recommended class when dealing with polynomials. Check out the documentation for more.

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

p1 = Polynomial([1,5,2])

p2 = Polynomial([6,1,4,3])

print(p1 * p2)
```

> Polynomial([  6.,  31.,  21.,  25.,  23.,   6.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand correctly, but I think this code can help you

```
for x in [-1, 0, 2, 3.4]:
print(x, p(x))
```